# how to make a function that check if the csv file is valid or not? (python)

Tags: python, csv

i have a csv file like so 
name: test1.csv

```
read_start,read_end
22,90
15,88
10,100
```

test2.csv

```
read_start,read_end
10,100
100,10
8,10
```

my question is
how do i make a code that can check if all the values in read_start is less than or equal to the ones in read_end return True
then return False if any value of read_start is greater than read_end

example:

> validate_alignment('test1.csv')

if i test this code it will returnn True

test2.csv will be False

this is  what i have tried

```
import csv

def validate_alignment(alignment_filename):
    file=open(alignment_filename)

    contentss=csv.reader(file)

    for x in contentss:

        if len(x)==0:
            return False
        elif len(x)!=0:
            if x[0]<x[1]:
                return True
            else:
                return False
```

Comment: What if they are equal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = csv.reader(open(alignment_filename,'r'))
data.next()

print all([row[0]<row[1] for row in data])
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<web session>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/hhyungchae/foc/mywork/dying2.py", line 8, in validate_alignment
    return all([row[0]<row[1] for row in data])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: do you have empty lines in your file? this error basically means that there isn't any row[0] or row[1] for some line in your file. If your file doesn't have standard data then you will need to handle that as well.

Comment: thank you so much! i did something wrong a while ago. it's working fine now! thanks. but um do you know how to make the function to only accept positive integers? @VIKASHJAISWAL

Answer (score 2):

```
import csv

def validate_alignment(alignment_filename):
    f = open(alignment_filename) # avoid using key word `file`

    f.readline()  # pass the head line

    contents = csv.reader(f)
    for row in contents:
        if len(row) == 0:
            return False
        row = map(int, row)  # cast read_start and read_end to integer
        if row[0] > row[1]:
            return False
    return True
```

Let's have a test:

```
>>> validate_alignment("test1.csv")
True
>>> validate_alignment("test2.csv")
False
```

I see `read_start,read_end` in the test1.csv, so I add `f.readline()` to pass the head line, if your actual data has no such line, just remove it from the code.

Comment: i got false for both test1 and test2 D:

Comment: @hwanghyungchae do you have empty line ?

Comment: sorry. i just tried it again and it worked didn't know why that happened. thanks for answering :D

Answer (score 0):

just return true only after you checked all lines

```
def validate_alignment(alignment_filename):
    file=open(alignment_filename)
    contentss=csv.reader(file)
    for x in contentss:
        if len(x)==0:
            return False
        elif int(x[0])>int(x[1]):
            return False
    return True
```